# How to import Diigo bookmarks into Delicious

Tags: bookmarks, delicious, diigo

I want to migrate all of my bookmarks in Diigo to Delicious but it seems there is no official functionality to import bookmarks from Delicious. Is there any browser add-on, script, webtool to import data in Delicious today?